# CollectionViewCell margin?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` and there are some dequeued custom cells in it. As you can see from the screenshot, there's this odd margin and I cannot figure out where this come from. The brown/orange color is the `UICollectionView` and the grey color is the `UICollectionViewCell`.

I'm using a xib file for that cell because I'd need many custom cells.

[image]

[image]

And the code that generates the `UICollectionView` has nothing that would cause this margin.

```
extension DashVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostImageCell", for: indexPath) as! PostImageCell
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.post = post
        cell.user = user
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func setCollectionViewDelegatesAndRowHeight()
    {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,   sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let width = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    let height = 407
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    return size
}
```

Comment: size of cell is not as per collectionview width! Provide size of collectionViewCell equals to the collectionview width!

Comment: which margin are you talking about? there are a few ones on your screenshot.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I tried with `let width = Int(collectionView.frame.width)` but it still doesn't work. The margin remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UICollectionView` width is 375 and `UICollectionViewCell` width is 320. You are seeing the difference. To make your cells as wide as the screen you can make your controller conform to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, and implement the following method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    cellHeight = 407.0
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, cellHeight);

    return size;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, it's not working though. I've updated my question above. Please see that. Also, the height of the cell needs to be dynamic because it may or may not contain more than 1 photo and/or content

Comment: You can use `cellForItemAt` to get the desired height instead of hardcoding it to 407. As for the width not working, did you put it in `extension UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`? And if you did, can you place a breakpoint/debug log and see if the function is being called or not?

Comment: Ahhhh, I forgot `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as extension! That's right. How do I get the dynamic height though? I get I can use `cellForItemAt` but I'm not sure how to achieve that. Any advice?

Comment: You can get the cell height for the indexPath by calling `cell.contentView.frame.size.height`.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried to create `var cellHeight = CGFloat()` then for `cellForItemAt indexPath` I've `cellHeight = cell.contentView.frame.size.height` to get the current cell size and then  used `cellHeight` to set it as a height in `sizeForItemAt` but it returned nothing. Only the `UICollectionView`, no cells whatsoever.